# Not able to use GetValueOrDefault() for Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I've defined a Dictionary with some custom type like this,

```
 public readonly Dictionary<PricingSection, View> _viewMappings = new Dictionary<PricingSection, View>();
```

Now when i try to do

```
_viewMappings.GetValueOrDefault(section);
```

section is of type `PricingSection`

i'm getting an error saying

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'Dictionary' does not contain a definition for 'GetValueOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'GetValueOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am i missing something ??

Comment: But why do you think that `Dictionary` contains that method?

Comment: @YuriiN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn466984%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

Comment: you provided method for **ImmutableDictionary** which is absolutely different from simple `Dictionary`.

Comment: In NETCore 2.2 it's an extension method for `IReadOnlyDictionary` which `Dictionary` implements. So this will work for 2.2.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Am i missing something ??

You are missing the fact `Dictionary` does not contain any method of this name `GetValueOrDefault`

[Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Maybe you are looking for

[Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, TValue) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Gets the value associated with the specified key.

or

[ImmutableDictionary.GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue> Method (IImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>, TKey)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn466984(v=vs.111).aspx)

> Gets the value for a given key if a matching key exists in the
> dictionary.

---

You could however implement your own

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict,TKey key)
      =>  dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : default(TValue);
}
```

---

If you are using any of the following, there are extension method overloads for `IReadOnlyDictionary`

- *NET* 5.0 RC1
- *.NET Core* 3.1 3.0 2.2 2.1 2.0
- *.NET Standard* 2.1

[`CollectionExtensions.GetValueOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=netcore-3.1)

> Tries to get the value associated with the specified key in
> the dictionary

Comment: Would it be better to implement the extension method on `IDictionary<>` or even `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>` instead of `Dictionary<>`?

Comment: `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<,>>` does not ensure key uniqueness, unlike `IDictionary<>`, therefore imo not as far as IEnumerable when you're actually extending for Dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

I use it in .Net Core (3.1)

class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> implements IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.

and there is and extension method in namespace System.Collections.Genericfor for IReadOnlyDictionary:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
     ...
     public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key) where TKey : notnull;
     ...
}
```

so we get it out of the box also for Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.

(Not sure about .net framework which going to be obsolete anyway)

Answer (score 1):

`GetValueOrDefault()` is part of  `ImmutableDictionary`. so of course you get the error message. instead use

`Dictionary.TryGetValue(TKey, TValue)`

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered the same problem, I was just missing this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic
```

As mentioned by @guyarad, this is an extension method on [IReadOnlyDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) but it needs to be imported. It seems obvious, but since you can use a returned dictionary without the import, it can be confusing when it mostly works but is missing some functionality you're pretty sure it should have.

Comment: I had the issue with the reference shown here being present